# How to make icon background transparent during dragging

Tags: css, drag-and-drop, blazor, transparency

I am experimenting with creating a web chess to practice drag-and-drop technique. I am doing it with Blazor context and my ambition is to only use HTML+CSS+C# and if possible avoid Javascript interop code.

It all works quite fine and looks pretty good. But one detail is still a bit annoying.

My chess pieces are currently generated as `<i>` elements with Fontawesome icons. When dragging a piece to another square it also brings its background color during the whole dragging. Can that be avoided? Is it possible to have the icon skip its "blocksize behaviour" and only bring its actual vector contour during the dragging?

PieceComponent.razor

```
@using System.Diagnostics
@if (Piece != null)
{
    <div class="draggable piece-container @DropClass" draggable="true" @ondragstart="@FlagMovingPiece">
        <PieceIcon Piece="@Piece" />
    </div>
}

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public Piece Piece { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public bool PieceAllowDrop
    {
        set
        {
            DropClass = value ? "drop-allow" : "drop-allow";
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<Piece> PieceIsMoving { get; set; }


    private string DropClass;

    private async Task FlagMovingPiece()
    {
        await PieceIsMoving.InvokeAsync(Piece);
    }
}
```

PieceComponent.razor.css

```
.piece-container {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
   
::deep .piece {
    font-size: 6vh;
    margin: auto;
}

::deep .piece-black {
    text-shadow: 0.1vh 0.1vh #888;
}

::deep .piece-white {
    text-shadow: 0.2vh 0.2vh #090909;
}
```

Piece.razor

```
@switch (Piece.PieceType)
{
    case PieceType.King:
        <i class="fas fa-chess-king @ColorClass"></i>
        break;
    case PieceType.Queen:
        <i class="fas fa-chess-queen @ColorClass"></i>
        break;
    case PieceType.Rook:
        <i class="fas fa-chess-rook @ColorClass"></i>
        break;
    case PieceType.Bishop:
        <i class="fas fa-chess-bishop @ColorClass"></i>
        break;
    case PieceType.Knight:
        <i class="fas fa-chess-knight @ColorClass"></i>
        break;
    case PieceType.Pawn:
        <i class="fas fa-chess-pawn @ColorClass"></i>
        break;
}


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Piece Piece { get; set; }

    private string ColorClass => Piece.Color == Color.Black ? "piece piece-black" : "piece piece-white";

}
```

PieceIcon.razor.css

```
.piece-black {
    color: #111;
}

.piece-white {
    color: #EEE;
}
```

Comment: Is there a special css class you can target when only dragging the element? It might help to share a snippet to get better answers.

Comment: Yes, if you can demonstrate the problem with a working snippet, we can help you much more efficiently.

Comment: I now added content of the relevant files. But I am afraid that won't help that much. I think the question is more related to generic HTML/CSS functionality than Blazor: Can an icon skip its background when dragging on a web page?